audio input plays back on output
I have a samson GO mic, to which I've connected my headphones. Sometimes, it will play back the input it receives on the microphone back on the headphones that I connected to it. On windows, the fix for this was to go to the sound settings and toggle "Listen to this device" on and back off, after which it was fixed for an indeterminate time.
Now I'm running NixOS, with pipewire and wireplumber, with support for pulse and alsa. pw-ctl gives back 6 connected ids for my microphone: Front Left and Front Right for playback, input monitor and microphone (input).
pactl list sinks short only gives back one sink for the device, as well as the monitor source, but again, no listen back or anything like that.
pavucontrol just shows one audio device with 2 channels as well, as well as the monitor and microphone inputs. Changing the configuration does not help this issue either. Currently I have it set to analog stereo duplex.
What could be causing this issue and how would I go about resolving it?
